# Riemann stieltjes integral concern

Tags: calculus

Suppose $f(x)=x^2=z$ and $g(x)=x^6$.Now $\int g(x) df(x)$ is an stieltjes integral which is evaluated as $\int z^3 dz$,then we apply the antiderivative concept like we did with an independent variable $x$.But the concept that differentiation is the reverse process of integration is only proved considering $x$ as an independent variable while here $z$ is not,why can then we treat $z$ in the same way as $x$?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what does "...which is evaluated as..." mean. By the basic properties of the RS integral, and since $\;f\;$ is continuously differentiable everywhere, we get that

$$\int g(x)\,d(f(x)) =\int\,g(x)\,f'(x)\,dx=2\int x^7\,dx=\frac14x^8+C$$

...though the RS integral is usually used with limits in the integral. In fact, I've never used RS integral without limits, so the above must be understood as integral $\;\int\limits_a^b g\,d(f)\;$ , with $\;a,b\in\Bbb R\;$ .